# How can the blood of gods be harvested if it doesn't spill naturally?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, gods

The Greek Gods were a large group of powerful humans with access to advanced technology, which put them on a level far surpassing ordinary human beings. One of their incredible attributes was their immortality and the ability to heal any wound or injury. This stemmed from a liquid that ran through their veins, known as ichor. Referred to as the blood of gods by lowly mortals, ichor was what bestowed the Olympians longevity and healing factor that they enjoyed. This liquid flows through the veins in the body like normal blood, but contains super-charged blood cells that cauterized and healed wounds much quicker than normal. When the skin is scraped, the blood cells in the ichor immediately clump together to clot the wound. This would then scab over and rebuild the damaged tissue, returning the area to normal within seconds. As it is such a powerful force, ichor has many other applications, such as powerful technology. Because of this, there is an underground market for godblood, in which it is bought and sold to aspiring entrepreneurs. This is difficult to attain as gods are far too powerful for humans to take on. Fortunately, there is another solution to be found in demigods.

Demigods are the offspring of true gods that were sired with mortals. Although they are less powerful than their godly parents, they still retain the ichor within their veins, making them a valuable source of energy. Due to the healing factor of true gods, their injuries heal before any blood is spilled, making it impossible to collect samples from them. Demigods heal only twice as fast as regular humans. Therefore, it should be simple to get a sample of blood from injuring them directly, such as cutting. However, it is discovered that ichor does not spill like normal blood at all, whether it comes from gods or their half mortal children.

based on these preconditions, How can individuals go about acquiring and selling the ichor?

Comment: You state directly in the question that ichor "contains super-charged blood cells that cauterized and healed wounds much quicker than normal." That seems like the answer to the base question itself, but I assume you would not have asked this question if it were that simple. What am I missing here?

Comment: Based on the introductionary text I expected a completely different question, having to do with either acquiring or selling the ichor. I feel a lot of the information here is not really relevant, and that, indeed, you answered your question already.

Comment: These are two contradicting questions. Title asks how to *prevent* spilling his blood (the description literally said they heal too fast, so it’s already answered); then the last sentence ask how to *harvest* the blood — from *demi-gods.* Please choose one single problem. VTC

Answer (score 1):

**Blood clotting In humans**

In humans, blood clotting normally occurs when there is damage to a blood vessel. Platelets immediately begin to adhere to the cut edges of the vessel and release chemicals to attract even more platelets. A platelet plug is formed, and the external bleeding stops.

**Donated blood contains anticoagulants**

The blood is usually stored in a flexible plastic bag that contains sodium citrate, phosphate, dextrose and sometimes adenine. This combination keeps the blood from clotting and preserves it during storage.

**Ichor in gods**

Ichor is doing clotting action but much faster.

**Preventing god blood extraction**

You need to stop the action of anticoagulants. This can be done by 2 ways.

- Make ichor's clotting action so fast that it clots the blood
  instantly when it leaves the blood vessel.
- Ichor destroys the anticoagulants before they could start their
  reaction.

Answer (score 1):

## Surgically:

Okay, so demigods heal fast, and the ichor clots fast. No problem. Many veins are near the surface of the skin, and a good set of sharp knives will let you cut the veins right out of the demigods. Fast healing will allow the veins to rapidly regrow, while the veins removed from the demigod will contain either clotted ichor (still ichor), or the ichor in the veins will still be in the veins and NOT clotted. Either way, you get ichor out of the body of the demigod.

By the way, as a person who spent 20 years working in a hospital lab, this clotting system would likely kill the demigods rapidly if there weren't a ready means of reversing it. The demigod would get a paper cut, the blood at the sight would insta-clot, and the clot would go into the blood stream and block vessels in the heart or brain. So I'd guess that something about being inside the vein causes the blood to stay fluid. Thus, I would predict that surgically removed veins would retain freshness and vitality even after the vein was removed from the body. The end would self-seal, leaving you a nice little tube of ichor for whatever you might need it for.

Answer (score 0):

The ichor cells must have some way of knowing that they have encountered a wound in order to trigger the clotting process.

There are two obvious possibilities:

1. Exposure to air. This would make gods and demigods still susceptible to blunt force trauma.
2. Chemical signals from damaged cells.

To protect against blunt force injuries that do not lead to air exposure, but also avoid overactive response that would cause more problems than it solves (excessive clotting is, itself, deadly), the reality is probably a mixture of the two--and even so, the intercellular signals must be rather complex.

Fortunately, both mechanisms can be circumvented by a single mechanism: the hypodermic needle.

When extracted through a needle, the ichor will never be directly exposed to air. Additionally, it can be collected from a blood vessel at a point several millimeters or more away from the actual wound site, so the highly localized intercellular signals won't cause it to coagulate. There may be healing going on in the immediate vicinity of the needle entry point, but that'll just seal it in and improve the isolation from air.

Chemical anticoagulants may make extraction more efficient and help preserve ichor once extracted, but just the simple needle ought to be sufficient to get started.